Why don't values fit on the page in editing mode but do actually fit when printing?
In editing mode with the view set on "page break preview" some values don't fit on the page.
However, if I go to print, they fit on the page.
How does this work?

It might not look like it, but I scrolled all the way to the left.
See also how the €-sign isn't displayed in editing mode.


Do you have "Scale to fit" settings set to "1 page" instead of Automatic?  https://i.sstatic.net/AJhgzQC8.png

perhaps instead of normal view use page layout or page break preview.
